# Вертикально выровнять радиокнопку

Tags: html, css

Как вертикально выровнять точку `.radio + label:before`, независимо сколько после неё будет текста
[codepen](https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/ZjprGp)

```css
.button-radio{
    padding: 15px 25px;
}

.radio {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
.button-radio label p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button-radio label p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.radio + label {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 55px;
    /* margin: 15px 25px; */
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.radio + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
}
.radio + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 19px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #9FD468;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .2s;
}

.radio:checked + label{
    background: #0f74a8;
    color: #fff;
}

.radio:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="group1" />
    <label for="radio">
      <p>
        radiobtn1
      </p>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="button-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio2" name="group1" />
    <label for="radio2">
      <p>
        radiobtn2
      </p>
      <p>
        radiobtn2
      </p>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.button-radio {
  padding: 15px 25px;
}

.radio {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}

.button-radio label p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button-radio label p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.radio+label {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 55px;
  /* margin: 15px 25px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.radio+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 15px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
}

.radio+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: 19px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

.radio:checked+label {
  background: #0f74a8;
  color: #fff;
}

.radio:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.radio:focus+label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" name="group1" />
  <label for="radio">
      <p>
        radiobtn1
      </p>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="button-radio">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio2" name="group1" />
  <label for="radio2">
      <p>
        radiobtn2 
      </p>
      <p>
        radiobtn2
      </p>
  </label>
</div>
```